# How to synchronize TIdHTTPServer::OnCommandGet with VCL

Tags: multithreading, c++builder, indy, vcl

I have this code in a VCL Forms application, written in C++Builder XE6, which is **not thread-safe**:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::HTTPServerCommandGet (TIdContext *AContext, TIdHTTPRequestInfo *ARequestInfo, TIdHTTPResponseInfo *AResponseInfo)
{
    ListHistory->Items->BeginUpdate();

    try
    {
        TListItem* Item = ListHistory->Items->Add();
        Item->Caption = Now().FormatString(_D("dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss"));
        Item->SubItems->Add(_D(""));
        Item->SubItemImages[0] = 0; // 0 = Incoming
        Item->SubItems->Add(ARequestInfo->RemoteIP);
        Item->SubItems->Add(ARequestInfo->Command + _D(" ") + ARequestInfo->URI);
        Item->SubItems->Add(ARequestInfo->Version);
        Item->SubItems->Add(ARequestInfo->RawHeaders->CommaText);
        if (ARequestInfo->PostStream)
            Item->SubItems->Add(ReadStringFromStream(ARequestInfo->PostStream));
        else
            Item->SubItems->Add(_D(""));
    }
    __finally
    {
        ListHistory->Items->EndUpdate();
    }

    // Process request.
    ...

    ListHistory->Items->BeginUpdate();

    try
    {
        TListItem* Item = ListHistory->Items->Add();
        Item->Caption = Now().FormatString(_D("dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss"));
        Item->SubItems->Add(_D(""));
        Item->SubItemImages[0] = 1; // 1 = Outgoing
        Item->SubItems->Add(AContext->Binding->IP);
        Item->SubItems->Add(IntToStr(AResponseInfo->ResponseNo) + _D(" ") + AResponseInfo->ResponseText);
        Item->SubItems->Add(ARequestInfo->Version);
        Item->SubItems->Add(AResponseInfo->RawHeaders->CommaText);
        Item->SubItems->Add(AResponseInfo->ContentText);
    }
    __finally
    {
        ListHistory->Items->EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

`ListHistory` is a `TListView`.

To make this code thread-safe, I need to synchronize access to all VCL components with the main thread.

I googled and searched StackOverflow, and found a lot of examples for Delphi that use anonymous methods with `TThread.Synchronize()`, but none for C++Builder. I also found that `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` are now deprecated and wrappers for `TThread::Synchronize()` and `TThread::Queue()`. That would make `Synchronize()` the method to use in my case.

What is the **simplest way** to make the above code thread-safe?

Can I simply create a `TListItem` in the `OnCommandGet` handler, store it as a data member of the `TForm1` class and call `Synchronize()` on a parameterless method of the `TForm1` class, that adds the stored `TListItem` to `ListHistory`? Or would that still not be thread-safe?

Do I need to store all item/subitem strings and the image index separately as data members of `TForm1`?

Or, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm pretty sure the OP understands that, but doesn't know HOW to accomplish that in C++ exactly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I understand the need to synchronize with the main VCL thread and to avoid race conditions. As Remy wrote, the question was how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I googled and searched StackOverflow, and found a lot of examples for Delphi that use anonymous methods with `TThread.Synchronize()`, but none for C++Builder.

This is covered in Embarcadero's documentation:

[How to Handle Delphi Anonymous Methods in C++](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B)

In a nutshell, if you are using one of the Clang-based compilers, you can simply pass a [C++ lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to `TThread::Synchronize()`. On the other hand, if you are using the "classic" Borland compiler instead, you can either:

- define a class that implements the `TThreadProcedure` interface and its `Invoke()` method, and then pass an instance of that class to the `_di_TThreadProcedure` overload of `TThread::Synchronize()`.
- define a class that implements a parameter-less method, and then create an instance of that class and pass a pointer to the method to the `TThreadMethod` overload of `TThread::Synchronize()`.

> I also found that `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` are now deprecated and wrappers for `TThread::Synchronize()` and `TThread::Queue()`.

Correct. However, even though they are deprecated, they have not been removed yet (that will come in Indy 11 or 12), so you *can* use them if you want to, for now.

> Can I simply create a `TListItem` in the `OnCommandGet` handler, store it as a data member of the `TForm1` class and call `Synchronize()` on a parameterless method of the `TForm1` class, that adds the stored `TListItem` to `ListHistory`? Or would that still not be thread-safe?

No, that would not be thread-safe.  `OnCommandGet` is called in a worker thread, and you can't just "create a `TListItem`" without going through the `TListView` and its underlying `HWND`, so that would need to be created in the main UI thread.  And, if you have multiple clients connected, you would need to serialize access to such a data member in the Form, causing a race condition.

> Do I need to store all item/subitem strings and the image index separately as data members of `TForm1`?

That is one way to go. However, if you have multiple clients connected, you would need to serialize access to those data members.

So, it is better to keep the values isolated for each event.

> Or, is there a better way to do this?

If you are using the "classic" compiler, I would suggest doing what `TIdSync` does internally.  Define a class with the data members you need, and then define a parameter-less method in that class to use the data members, and pass that method to `TThread::Synchronize()`, eg:

```cpp
class TAddToListHistory
{
public:
    TListView *History;
    TIdContext *Context;
    TIdHTTPRequestInfo *Request;
    TIdHTTPResponseInfo *Response;

    void __fastcall AddRequest()
    {
        History->Items->BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            TListItem* Item = History->Items->Add();
            Item->Caption = Now().FormatString(_D("dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss"));
            Item->SubItems->Add(_D(""));
            Item->SubItemImages[0] = 0; // 0 = Incoming
            Item->SubItems->Add(Request->RemoteIP);
            Item->SubItems->Add(Request->Command + _D(" ") + Request->URI);
            Item->SubItems->Add(Request->Version);
            Item->SubItems->Add(Request->RawHeaders->CommaText);
            if (Request->PostStream)
                Item->SubItems->Add(ReadStringFromStream(Request->PostStream));
            else
                Item->SubItems->Add(_D(""));
        }
        __finally
        {
            History->Items->EndUpdate();
        }
    }

    void __fastcall AddResponse()
    {
        History->Items->BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            TListItem* Item = History->Items->Add();
            Item->Caption = Now().FormatString(_D("dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss"));
            Item->SubItems->Add(_D(""));
            Item->SubItemImages[0] = 1; // 1 = Outgoing
            Item->SubItems->Add(Context->Binding->IP);
            Item->SubItems->Add(IntToStr(Response->ResponseNo) + _D(" ") + Response->ResponseText);
            Item->SubItems->Add(_D("HTTP/1.1")/*Request->Version*/);
            Item->SubItems->Add(Response->RawHeaders->CommaText);
            Item->SubItems->Add(Response->ContentText);
        }
        __finally
        {
            History->Items->EndUpdate();
        }
    }
};

void __fastcall TForm1::HTTPServerCommandGet(TIdContext *AContext,
    TIdHTTPRequestInfo *ARequestInfo, TIdHTTPResponseInfo *AResponseInfo)
{
    TAddToListHistory adder;
    addr.History = ListHistory;
    addr.Context = AContext;
    addr.Request = ARequestInfo;
    addr.Response = AResponseInfo;

    TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &addr.AddRequest);

    // Process request.
    ...

    TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &addr.AddResponse);
}
```

If you are using a Clang-based compiler, then using lambdas would be simpler, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::HTTPServerCommandGet(TIdContext *AContext,
    TIdHTTPRequestInfo *ARequestInfo, TIdHTTPResponseInfo *AResponseInfo)
{
    TThread::Synchronize(nullptr,
        [=]{
            ListHistory->Items->BeginUpdate();
            try
            {
                TListItem* Item = ListHistory->Items->Add();
                Item->Caption = Now().FormatString(_D("dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss"));
                Item->SubItems->Add(_D(""));
                Item->SubItemImages[0] = 0; // 0 = Incoming
                Item->SubItems->Add(ARequestInfo->RemoteIP);
                Item->SubItems->Add(ARequestInfo->Command + _D(" ") + ARequestInfo->URI);
                Item->SubItems->Add(ARequestInfo->Version);
                Item->SubItems->Add(ARequestInfo->RawHeaders->CommaText);
                if (ARequestInfo->PostStream)
                    Item->SubItems->Add(ReadStringFromStream(ARequestInfo->PostStream));
                else
                    Item->SubItems->Add(_D(""));
            }
            __finally
            {
                ListHistory->Items->EndUpdate();
            }
        }
    );

    // Process request.
    ...

    TThread::Synchronize(nullptr,
        [=]{
            ListHistory->Items->BeginUpdate();
            try
            {
                TListItem* Item = ListHistory->Items->Add();
                Item->Caption = Now().FormatString(_D("dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss"));
                Item->SubItems->Add(_D(""));
                Item->SubItemImages[0] = 1; // 1 = Outgoing
                Item->SubItems->Add(AContext->Binding->IP);
                Item->SubItems->Add(IntToStr(AResponseInfo->ResponseNo) + _D(" ") + AResponseInfo->ResponseText);
                Item->SubItems->Add(_D("HTTP/1.1")/*ARequestInfo->Version*/);
                Item->SubItems->Add(AResponseInfo->RawHeaders->CommaText);
                Item->SubItems->Add(AResponseInfo->ContentText);
            }
            __finally
            {
                ListHistory->Items->EndUpdate();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, Remy. I really appreciate it. I'm still using the 'Classic' compiler, so I will go for the `TAddToHistory` class solution, but those lambdas make this task very easy. I will definitely consider switching to a Clang-based compiler somewhere in the future...

Comment: I noticed that you set the protocol version of the response to a fixed string "HTTP/1.1". Does TIdHTTPServer always respond in HTTP/1.1, even when it receives an HTTP/1.0 request?

Comment: @MartinNijhoff yes it does. There is a TODO in its code to respond with the same version as the request, but that is not implemented yet